# Will my dataset be too small to do linear regression/polynomial regression?

Tags: regression, dataset, linear

Basically, I have a dataset with 80000 entries regarding aviation accidents from 1950 - 2019. Since the data from 1950 - 1982 have many 0s and the ones that are not zero has 1/2 as the number of accident, I decided that they are relatively anomalous, so I disregard it and only used 1982 - 2019.

I tallied up the number of accidents happening in each year and made a new dataframe. so now I have a dataframe with 2 columns and 37 rows, compared to the previous dataset where I had 80000 rows. Is the new dataframe too small for me to do linear regression? Are there alternatives for doing these kinds of problem?

Comment: Binary logistic regression for accident vs no accidents instead?

Comment: I only have dataset for anytime an accident occur, i dont see how it could predict if it will occur or not

Comment: You have 80000 entries with 37 as "accidents" and the remainder as "no accident"